# Py4JJavaError: Using Pyspark in Jupyter notebook trying to run examples using "spark."

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the examples (for example spark/examples/src/main/python/ml/fpgrowth_example.py) for PySpark in Jupyter notebook. However, I am getting exceptions any time I try to do "spark.(some function)" In the case of this example, it is spark.createDataFrame, but I have also tried spark.read and it resulted in the same exception. I have also tried creating my own sparkSession, and using the one that is already in Jupyter notebook on start, and neither worked correctly. The main excpetion I can find is AnalysisException: `'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'`

Code:

```
# $example on$
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth 
# $example off$
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("FPGrowthExample")\
    .getOrCreate()

# $example on$
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, [1, 2, 5]),
    (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
    (2, [1, 2])
], ["id", "items"])
```

Exception:

> ```
> AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-2-512249e97d93> in <module>()
>       3         (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
>       4         (2, [1, 2])
> ----> 5     ], ["id", "items"])
>
> D:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>     691             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
>     692         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
> --> 693         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())
>     694         df = DataFrame(jdf, self._wrapped)
>     695         df._schema = schema
>
> D:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
>    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
>    1256         return_value = get_return_value(
> -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>    1258 
>    1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> D:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>      67                                              e.java_exception.getStackTrace()))
>      68             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: '):
> ---> 69                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
>      70             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis'):
>      71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
>
> AnalysisException: 'java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> D:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>      62         try:
> ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>      64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>
> D:\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>     327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>     329             else:
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
> : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.internalCreateDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:577)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(SparkSession.scala:752)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(SparkSession.scala:737)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>   at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:180)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
>   ... 30 more
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1523)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
>   ... 45 more
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
>   ... 51 more
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For Spark version 2.3.1, I was able to create the Data frame like:

```
df = spSession.createDataFrame(someRDD)
```

by removing this function from the 45 from the file \spark\python\pyspark\shell.py

```
    SparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf()
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .enableHiveSupport() <--- Delete this line
        .getOrCreate()
```

I can't explain it further, but I imagine that as I don't have Hive installed in my Windows 10, removing this line makes PySpark not to use Hive and use any other thing that works to create the DataFrame. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Working for me with the following steps

JAVA8: https://www.guru99.com/install-java.html

Anakonda : https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Pyspark in jupyter : https://changhsinlee.com/install-pyspark-windows-jupyter/

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\

    .builder\

    .appName("FPGrowthExample")\

    .getOrCreate()

# $example on$
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, [1, 2, 5]),
    (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
    (2, [1, 2])
], ["id", "items"])

df.show()
```

```
+---+------------+
| id|       items|
+---+------------+
|  0|   [1, 2, 5]|
|  1|[1, 2, 3, 5]|
|  2|      [1, 2]|
+---+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, where the error occurs when i am executing show() function in pyspark, later i found python3 location is missing in Python installed folder where i copy the python setup file in same path and renamed to python3 in the same path, the issue is not occurring

make sure where we have multiple version of python installed in system we are making sure python3 setup file available in execution Environment

**It worked for me**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).